# What additional equipment is needed for bowfishing?

Tags: fishing, archery, bow-fishing

As it is the time of year when carp spawn and are in close to shore, I have been seeing people along the lakeshore with archery equipment, bow fishing for carp.

If one were to already have a bow and arrows, what **additional equipment would be needed to go bowfishing?**

Comment: Clearly you'll want an array of depth finders, a huge bass boat, and filming equipment.

Comment: Fishing line. Bow mounted reels are probably more convenient than dispensing it from hand held coils.

Answer (score 2):

Although probably not necessary, polarized sunglasses are extremely useful to spot the fish - especially on a sunny day.